# Best way to submit many (equally named) parameters in GET/REST

Tags: rest

For a REST interface:

What is the best way to allow the client to set many equally named parameters in a GET?

For example if the client should specify multiple possible colors

```
www.example.com/products/{color=green|color=yellow|color=white| ...}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this would be fine:

```
GET http://www.example.com/products?colors=green,yellow,white
```

Despite popular opinion, there is no REST constraint that says you should not use query string parameters.

Comment: From the looks of the question, query string parameters are appropriate. It appears to be a search request and that is what query parameters are for.

Answer (score 2):

Considering browsers consider the application/x-form-urlencoded and the querystring equivalent, and considering several values can be provided for the same name, you can simply do
color=red&color=green&color&blue.

Provided your framework of choice handles this correctly, this should be jsut fine.